# Writing to file based on array value

Tags: php, fwrite

I have created an array which contains;

1. The filepath where the item is to be written.
2. the contents that I wish to be written to the file

The code for my array is:

```
foreach ($NewLang as $row => $val)
{
    $writefile = implode(",", $val);

    $filepath = $val[0];
}
```

This will display something like this:

> basket.lang.php,LANG_BASKETUPDATED,Basket Updated,

My question is how can I use `file_put_contents()` to write each line based on the value stored in `$val[0]`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking how to read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: The filepath changes for each line, I can write it easily enough if the filepath is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating a function for writing the files and placing it in the foreach loop instead.

Now my foreach loop looks like this:

```
foreach ($NewLang as $row => $val)
{   
    {   
        append_define($val[0], $val[1], $val[2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
file_put_contents($filepath, $writefile);
```

The content of $writefile would be written into the file that's name is inside $filepath

e.g.

```
$writefile="This is\na test";
$filepath="~/output.txt";
file_put_contents($filepath, $writefile);
```

This would write a file in you home path named 'output.txt'
which will contain the 2 lines

> This is
>
> a test